# Is there another way to choose which element in a drop down menu is selected?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Given a drop down menu of the form

```
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

the normal way to choose which option is selected by default is to add the `selected` attribute to the option tag. i.e. `<option selected>`.

However, for my purposes, it would be much easier if I could use an attribute in the `<select>` tag to choose which option is selected by default.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could make some JavaScript to add a variable there. But I am pretty sure the standard HTML way to do that is easier.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1 (pure JS):

Get all select with class name `sel`, use forEach to set selected value by the value of default attribute.

```js
var sel = document.getElementsByClassName('sel');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(sel ,function(ele){  
   ele.value = ele.getAttribute('default');
});
```

```html
<select default="2" class="sel">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<br>
<select default="3"  class="sel">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

### Option 2 (with jQuery):

use an each method to select all  element, set the selected option to the default attribute.

```js
//init default
$('select').each(function(){
  $(this).val($(this).attr('default'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select default="2">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<br>
<select default="3">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```